# how to calculation cost time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
id|order_id|order_no|order_status|remark|handle_time|create_time|update_time
11237|3942|2018050307542800005985|新建订单||20180503075428|2018/5/3 07:54:28|2018/5/3 07:54:28
11238|3943|2018050307591600005986|新建订单||20180503075916|2018/5/3 07:59:16|2018/5/3 07:59:16
11239|3943|2018050307591600005986|新建订单||20180503082115|2018/5/3 08:21:15|2018/5/3 08:21:15
11240|3943|2018050307591600005986|新建订单||20180503083204|2018/5/3 08:32:04|2018/5/3 08:32:04
11241|3941|2018050308564400005991|新建订单||20180503085644|2018/5/3 08:56:02|2018/5/3 08:56:44
11242|3941|2018050222320800001084|初审成功||20180503085802|2018/5/3 08:58:02|2018/5/3 08:58:02
11243|3941|2018050222320800001084|审核成功||20180503085821|2018/5/3 08:59:21|2018/5/3 08:58:21
11244|3945|2018050309152000005993|新建订单||20180503091520|2018/5/3 09:15:21|2018/5/3 09:15:21
```

Above is the data from my txt file.  It contains order information for stock trades.

I want to calculate the time difference for the create_time column for each unique order_id.  How do I do this with Pandas?

For example order_id 3941, there are three entries.  The difference in create_time from the first to the second entry is 2 minutes, and the difference from the 2nd to the 3rd entry is 1 minute.

The final output looks like below:

```
order_id,stage1_time,stage2_time,...
3941,2,1,...
```

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Guess you get down votes because of the unclear question and text.  From the question, there seem to be no relation between create_time, stage and the 'from'  'to' times.  Also, it would be better if you include the expected output

Comment: I have update my question ,thanks.

Comment: Why dont you replace the Chinese? character strings for order_status with equivalent English strings and update the question again? That would help the members to suggest you some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're asking.  You just want to have a new dataframe that calculates the time difference between the three different entries for each unique order id?

So, I start by creating the dataframe:

```
data = [
    [11238,3943,201805030759165986,'新建订单',20180503075916,'2018/5/3 07:59:16','2018/5/3 07:59:16'],
    [11239,3943,201805030759165986,'新建订单',20180503082115,'2018/5/3 08:21:15','2018/5/3 08:21:15'],
    [11240,3943,201805030759165986,'新建订单',20180503083204,'2018/5/3 08:32:04','2018/5/3 08:32:04'],
    [11241,3941,201805030856445991,'新建订单',20180503085644,'2018/5/3 08:56:02','2018/5/3 08:56:44'],
    [11242,3941,201805022232081084,'初审成功',20180503085802,'2018/5/3 08:58:02','2018/5/3 08:58:02'],
    [11243,3941,201805022232081084,'审核成功',20180503085821,'2018/5/3 08:59:21','2018/5/3 08:58:21']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id','order_id','order_no','order_status','handle_time','create_time','update_time'])
df.loc[:, 'create_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, 'create_time'])
```

Sort values by order_id and then create_time:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['order_id', 'create_time'])
```

Next, I group by order id and select the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd entry:

```
first_df = df.groupby('order_id').nth(0)
second_df = df.groupby('order_id').nth(1)
third_df = df.groupby('order_id').nth(2)
```

Subtract the 1st from the second to get the 1st stage, and subtract the 2nd from the 3rd to get the second stage.  Then combine them into an output dataframe:

```
stage_two = third_df.loc[:, 'create_time'] - second_df.loc[:, 'create_time']
stage_one = second_df.loc[:, 'create_time'] - first_df.loc[:, 'create_time']
stages = pd.concat([stage_one, stage_two], axis=1, keys=['stage_one', 'stage_two'])

print(stages)
```

And the output looks like:

```
     stage_one stage_two
order_id                    
3941      00:02:00  00:01:19
3943      00:21:59  00:10:49
```